# How to run D code program in visual studio? Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: d

Althougt I had installed dub,dmd. I can run test.d in terminal.But I can't run file test.d in visual studio code.

Maybe should change launch.son file?

Answer (score 2):

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "(gdb) Launch",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/mct.d",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": false,
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "setupCommands": [
            {
                "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Launch.json file

Answer (score 0):

```
"program": "${workspaceRoot}/mct.d"
```

This should be a path to the executable, not the source file. Try:

```
"program": "${workspaceRoot}/mct.exe"
```